# CSV column is being return as null

Tags: c#, parsing, csv

I have parsing a CSV via the Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 provider. Which has been working fine for  most of our tasks, but recently I've noticed an issue.

I have a CSV which has a column called Rating, this is generally an integer but occasionally it will be "1-2" or a Date e.g "1/1/2010". The datatable I am importing it into has had its columns explicitly set to strings but when a non-integer field is read it is null instead.

Any ideas how I get round this??

Comment: do you read this into dataset? are you sure dataset column type is not integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a schema.ini file (in the folder that contains your .csv) and specify the columns data types correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Likely what is happening is that the first few fields in the column are being sniffed to determine data type, and then when there are later columns of a different type, they're dropped.

I believe you can turn off this behavior by adding `IMEX=1` to your `Extended Properties` in the connection string. This sets the reader to Intermixed Mode which will read the fields as text. Then you can go through in another pass and set the types yourself.

Comment: I get the same error as with the schema.ini file when I try this